# async.each/forEachOf entering next iteration without calling callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to use `async` to iterate over a directory of images within an async `waterfall` array of functions.

```
async.waterfall([
function(callback){
  async.forEachOf(waterfallObj.sizeDirs, function(sizeDir, index, cb){
      //get image files
      fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, sizeDir), function(err, files){
        tempFiles = files;
        console.log(index); //0 1 2 3 4
        //cb();
      });
  });

  callback(null);
}, /*more functions*/
]);
```

The idea is that I don't want to do the next iteration in the `forEachOf` loop until the `readdir` finishes reading files. To my understanding, `forEachOf` will not enter the next cycle of its loop until its callback is called (just like each function in async `waterfall` or `series`. However even with `cb()` commented out like I have above, I still see the index printed 5 times. Why does it not stop with the first iteration? How can I ensure the the readdir will finish before the next iteration if `cb` does not do this? What is `cb` supposed to do exactly if not this? (I've also had this same effect using `async.each`. Should I be using native `forEach` perhaps?

Comment: *"Why does it not stop with the first iteration"* Because it is not designed to work like `async.series`. That's why there's a `async.forEachOfSeries` method.

Answer (score 2):

That's the whole point of an asynchronous process, you don't wait for a request to finish before firing the next one. You fire all requests and they will get resolved one by one and each one of them will call it's callback as soon as the thread is free (and, of course, the request has finished).

Maybe you are looking for the promise approach, where you can chain your promises so that when one promise gets resolved, the next request will be fired and create a new promise, which, redundantly, you will be able to chain your third request, and so on.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the callback? Just to throw an error in the final callback if something fails?

Comment: Also, how would `async.each` be different for a native `for-loop` or `forEach-loop`?

Comment: I notice that when I'm doing a `waterfall` in async, if I get an array and I want to iterate over it inside some inner function, I have to do `async.waterfall([
function (callback) {
    async.each(arr, function (item, cb) {
        fs.readFile(item, function (err, contents) {
            console.log(contents);
            cb();
        });
    }, function () {
        callback();
    });
}]);`. If I do `arr.forEach` and just put `callback()` after it, i get scripts executing in unexpected orders. why isn't  `arr.forEach` blocking execution of `callback` until it's done?